# Is there a way to sibling non-active div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, siblings

I want to get all elements that do not have an "active" class.
this is my script :

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#Home"><i class="fas fa-home btn active"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#About"><i class="fas fa-user-astronaut btn"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#Contact"><i class="fas fa-file-contract btn"></i></a>
        </li>
      </nav>
```

Javascript:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    if (btn.length > 0) {
      elements[0].className = elements[0].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    btn[i].className += " active";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I want to get all elements that do not have an "active" class.***

You can use `:not(.active)` like:

```
var nonActive = document.querySelectorAll(".btn:not(.active)");
```

You can use `active` class in the `a` element instead of `i`.
I think you can achieve what you are looking in the following way:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("a");
Array.from(btn).forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    Array.from(btn).forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
li{
 list-style-type: none;
}
.active{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#Home" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home btn"></i>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#User"><i class="fas fa-user-astronaut btn"></i>User</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#Contact"><i class="fas fa-file-contract btn"></i>Contact</a>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: @tom-minor If you need to convert the results from `querySelectorAll()` to an array as well, spreading the resulting NodeList 
e.g.: `[...querySelectorAll()]` or `Array.from(querySelectorAll())` should work easily with the above implementation